# Circular singly-linked list

Tags: c#, list

This is a homework assignment

"Develop a structure for holding a singly-linked list. Create a list with a cycle. Create an algorithm that makes sure that the list is circular (the structure for holding elements of the list must be implemented by you)"

It probably sounds confusing and the fact that I am translating doesn't help. As I understand it, I need to create a custom singly linked list, which would go back to the first item after reaching its end.

I would really appreciate any ideas on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what each node in a singly linked list "knows" (i.e. what data it stores). Then think about what it means to make a circular list. What's the "next" element after the last one?

Hopefully that's enough of a hint to get you started.

Comment: It stores only its next neighbour, as I understand, but I am still confused about how the structure of my program should look like. It goes back to first after the last, of course, but I am still kind of lost.

Comment: @Max: Lost about what exactly? How far have you got? It sounds like there are two pieces of code you need to write: the list itself, and a test for it. Which are you finding difficult?

Comment: Max, start with the structure of just a node.

Comment: Both, to tell the truth. I've created two generic classes, one for the element of the list, one for the list itself. The element class is a generic class with one field for data that it takes, and one field "Next" of type "Element" itself. Now in the List class do I need to introduce three variables like first, current and last? I guess I also need an Add method to fill the list with values later for testing, what else do I need? I am sorry if it sounds stupid, I am a total novice.

Comment: @Max: The list itself wouldn't keep track of where you are within it - it just needs to know a reference to the head of the list. Think what you need to in order to *use* the list.

Comment: OK, so the next element to my current element should always be the head of the list, so I need head, current and next, correct?

Comment: @Max: For the list itself? That just needs the head (in practice many implementations also keep the size, but most real implementations also prevent cycles too). There's no concept of "current" in the list itself. An *element* needs to know the current value and a reference to the next element though.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a pointer to the head node which you should be sure not to lose as you make additions to and deletions from your list.A circular list is traversed using the do...while construct as against the while construct you use for traversing a singly-linked list.Rest of the operations are pretty much the same as for a singly-linked list.